# how to group transaction entries?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have this transactions table on my dvd store app:

#### Transactions

```
+----+-----------+--------------------+---------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| id | member_id | transaction_number | amount  |          type          |                  note                   |
+----+-----------+--------------------+---------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|  1 |      1000 | CD100001           | 100,000 | prepaid_deposit        |                                         |
|  2 |      1000 | CA100001           | -90,000 | prepaid_adjustment     | wrong input (10,000 instead of 100,000) |
|  3 |      1000 | FC100001           | -10     | membership_fee         |                                         |
|  4 |      1000 | FP100001           | 10      | membership_fee_payment |                                         |
|  5 |      1000 | PR100001           | -100    | dvd_purchase           |                                         |
|  6 |      1000 | PP100001           | 100     | dvd_purchase_payment   |                                         |
|  7 |      1000 | OC100001           | -10     | surcharge_fee          | past due for 2 days                     |
|  8 |      1000 | OP100001           | 10      | surcharge_fee_payment  |                                         |
|  9 |      1000 | SF100002           | 10      | surcharge_fee_payment  |                                         |
| 10 |      1000 | SF100002           | -10     | fee_adjustment         | duplicate payment recorded              |
+----+-----------+--------------------+---------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

I need to fetch the following records easily

1. total prepaid amount
2. total unpaid membership fee amount
3. total unpaid fees (membership and surcharge) amount
4. total unpaid purchases amount
5. total credit amount
6. total debit amount
7. total fee adjustments amount
8. total adjustments (prepaid deposit, fee and purchase adjustment amount)

I am thinking of adding fields like category (payment,charge,purchase,adjustment) and category_group (prepaid,fee,dvd) so that I can get the balance of entries per group but I don't know how to group it correctly.

I just what to know what is the better transaction design for my case. I wanted to record all transaction in one table. A transaction entry can be a purchase (dvd),  fee ( either membership,surcharge or delivery ), deposit (prepaid credits) , payment (for fee or purchase,) and adjustment for all wrong entry in purchases, fees, payments.